# Proving a function is differentiable, piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** Prove that the function $g:(-2,2) \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is differentiable at all points in $(-2,2)$

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{4-x^2},  & \text{if $x$ $\in$ (-2,0]} \\
2, & \text{if $x$ $\in (0,2)$}
\end{cases}$$

**Attempt**

I can't see how this function is differentiable at $x=0$ and therefore I can't see how it would be differentiable across the whole domain. The main issue I have here is proving that $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: Edit: Minor typo: "all points (-2,2)" missing the word "in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text {For } x<0 \text { we have: }\quad \frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac {\sqrt {4-x^2}-2}{x}=$$ $$=\frac {\sqrt {4-x^2}-2}{x} \cdot \frac {\sqrt {4-x^2}+2}{\sqrt {4-x^2}+2}=$$ $$=\frac {(4-x^2)-4}{x(\sqrt {4-x^2}+2)}=\frac {-x}{\sqrt {4-x^2}+2}$$ which tends to $0$ as $x\to 0.$ And (obviously) for $x>0$ we have $(f(x)-f(0)/(x-0)=0.$ So $f'(0)-0.$

Take a look at the graph to get an idea of what $f$ does near $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For functions of the form $$g(x)=\begin{cases}g_1(x)&a<x\le 0\\g_2(x)&0<x<b\end{cases}$$
to be differentiable at $x=0$, it is *sufficient* that $g_1$, $g_2$ are defined in a neighbourhood of $0$, are differentiable at $x=0$, and that $g_1(0)=g_2(0)$ and $g_1'(0)=g_2'(0)$.

Comment: Yes I know this, however I am not getting g_1'(0)=g_2'(0)

Comment: Sorry! I totally understand where I've messed up

Comment: I suppose you mean the left/right derivatives of $g_1,g_2$. As $g_i$ are only defined on a half interval around $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the limit of the difference quotient from both sides of 0 and show that the two one-sided limits agree, and therefore $g'$ is diff'l at $0$.

Comment: That is what I attempted to do however I am getting that first limit tends to 0

Comment: @THISISIT453 OK, so $g'(0)=0$.

Comment: No but then the limit from the right hand side is 2 right? So they are not equivalent?

Comment: The limits are indeed equal @THISISIT453 -- and it looks like you have found your mistake, so good work!  And feel free to up-vote my answer and select the answer that you think was best - Hagen's answer is the obvious choice :-)